# How do I find the transfer function from this step response diagram?

Tags: control

I'm having trouble understanding how to calculate the system's transfer function, given this diagram.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand step-by-step how to think about this problem?
Specifically, I don't understand how exactly I can calculate the natural frequency and damping ratio.

From the step response plot, the peak overshoot, defined as Mp=(2.8−2)/2=0.4 So, replacing that estimated Mp in the formula with ln: ζ≈0.3
And now I'm blocked.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to be more specific. This looks like a homework question with zero effort.

Comment: sorry, i m new on this platform. i want to know how can i calculate the damped natural frequency.                                                                                                    
From the step response plot, the peak overshoot, defined as

Mp=(2.8−2)/2=0.4

So, replacing that estimated Mp in the formula with ln:
ζ≈0.3

Comment: The diagram you have drawn shows distinct signs of representing a more complex transfer function than that seen from the usual examples. Add your working out into your question; not in comments.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you for your feedback, i appreciate!

Comment: Please move the information in your comment to the question. Learn how to enter equations in the site help.. Add sufficient information to your question (especially your own work) to get good answers.

Comment: Regarding overshoot: I would guess that the maximum is app. at 2.5 (and not at 2.8)

Answer (score 1):

There are some distinct problems with the waveform drawn in your picture that put your assumptions about it being purely a 2nd order transfer function onto shaky ground: -

[image]

The above picture is from a tool I use and I set it to have a ζ of 0.3 with a step input of unity. I've highlighted two areas (purple and light-blue) where your drawn waveform has problems in not corresponding with a 2nd order system.

- In purple, the step response starts gradually but, in your picture it starts immediately
- In light-blue there will be diminishing overshoot and undershoot but, your picture does not show this at all so, when you say this: -

> *Can anyone help me understand step-by-step how to think about this
> problem?*

That's what I'm trying to do (by pointing out that the response is not what I would call a typical homework standard as you have assumed it to be). Of course, it could have been drawn by someone not in full receipt of training/schooling (or someone who is lazy or foolish) who believed it was depicting a 2nd order low-pass system.

Comment: Yes - I agree with your conclusions. But we should consider that the diagram as shown from the TO seems to be a handwritten curve only. When there is an overshoot, it always will end up in an oscillation (diminishing over- and undershoots) - even when it is hard to see it in a graph.